# Set Timeout for queries using python or pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, lambda

I am using `read_sql()` for running the oracle query but I want to set a timeout as well for it.

```
def get_query_dataframe(db_connection, sql_query, pd):
    """
    Query the database and return the results in a dataframe

    Args:
        db_connection (cx_Oracle Connection): DB connection
        sql_query (string): Query to be run against the db
        pd (pandas): pandas lib

    Returns:
        pd.Dataframe - Dataframe of DB query results
    """
    return pd.read_sql(sql_query, db_connection)
```

I tried to put timeout option in the read_sql() but it failed with the below error message

> File "/var/task/src/main.py", line 35, in handler
> df = pd.read_sql(f"select count(1) from {oracledb_table_name}", conn, timeout=1)
> TypeError: read_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'[ERROR] Exception

Comment: What happens when you run the query manually from SQL?

Comment: it is running for long time and getting stucked not showing any output. so we are killing the queries manually

Comment: I need a solution in which I can put timeout option as well

Comment: You should work out why it is taking time: do you have locks, is it just slow, do you need indexes etc.  But at the python level you can set [`call_timeout`](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.call_timeout) on the driver connection (both in [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) and it's older incarnation cx_Oracle).

Comment: what would be the python-oracle db connection string look like? its giving me error when i am using this
conn = oracledb.connect(user=username, password=password, host=db_host, port=db_port, service_name=db_sid,timeout=30)

Comment: Check the documentation for syntax - there is no `timeout` but there is a `tcp_connect_timeout` parameter which does something different to what your question wants: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#oracledb.connect You would set call_timeout later after the connection has been obtained.